# Start brew-installed applications from terminal

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I just set up homebrew on my new macbook and used the `brew` and `brew cask` commands to install some applications. I can now open the applications from the launchpad but not from the terminal.

I know it's not working because the applications have not been saved to one of the directories in my `$PATH` variable, but none of the installation guides I have read for homebrew mention how you can set it up to put links to the binaries there. Some tutorials mention you should change the order of directories in your `/etc/paths` file, but I already did that and my problem persists.

Can anyone help me out? :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

This prepends /usr/local/bin to your existing $PATH.

Comment: ... settings apply on newly loaded terminal windows

Comment: This did not solve my problem, unfortunately (I quit and restarted the terminal of course). Installing an app with `brew cask` puts the .app file into `/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/`, and a symlink is created at `~/Applications`. `usr/local/bin` doesn't contain any of the installed apps, though.

Comment: Turns out this only applies to apps installed via `brew cask`. `brew`-installed apps are fine.

Comment: I want to start `iterm2` which is in `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/iterm2`. But I do not know how.